# No output from scapy packet handler

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

(os: pop_os 20.04)
I am trying out a very simple scapy script to sniff packets, but no matter how i simplify the script I am getting no output (just a blinking cursor):

```
from scapy.all import *

def packet_handler(pkt) :
    # if packet has 802.11 layer, and type of packet is Data frame
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) and pkt.type == 2:
            # do your stuff here
            print(pkt.show())

sniff(iface='wlp4s0mon', prn=packet_handler)
```

There are no errors, and ifconfig:

```
wlp4s0mon: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec E2-A6-A0-23-39-67-40-3A-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 40  bytes 9277 (9.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 40  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

seems to be right.  I have written many variations of the above, i have included what i consider to be the most simplified in an effort to debug the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I wanted Dot11FCS:

```
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11FCS) and pkt.type == 2:
```

although i am not completely sure why.

Comment: This is fixed in the github version of scapy.